# Can I replace a 12 V 40 W heating element with several 12 V 7 W elements?

Tags: power, heat, watts

**Here is the environment:** An RV fridge has a heat exchanger for cooling, looks like what you would stick on an IC chip, only 12" square. It has heater stuck on the back of it that is activated for the defrost cycle. This heater is 12 V, 40 W, 3.6 ohms, and is protected with a 7.5 A fuse.

**Here is the problem:** The heating element failed, they are no longer made, and they are sold out everywhere, I have contacted the OEM, no parts.

**What I want to do:** Toss the original part and replace it with something(s) that will look like the original to the diagnostics (3.6 ohms - I think is the test). I found some elements - 12 V 7 W ? ohms. I was thinking that I could put 6 of them in parallel and end up with 42 W.

**My Motivation:** If the handyman looking through a salvage yard right now finds one, he will sell it to me for $250 plus $80 to drive out here and another $80 to install it. Those elements I mention will cost me about $40 and I can install them myself.

Will the extra 2 W burn out the power board or is that a trivial amount of extra power? And, of course, is there a better, smarter way to solve this problem, besides continuing to search for a more exact fit?

Comment: Sounds fine from your description, but the devil is in the details. How does it look mechanically?

Comment: Yes. an extra 5% should not burn something out, although perhaps something will get a little bit hotter and not last quite as long. The tolerance on this thing is probably 5% anyway. Yes, you may run into non-electronic problems such as how to actually fit the heater modules in the space available. You can also consider making your own, since high-power resistors are not expensive.

Comment: That heater is used in defrost cycle. Smaller wattage will be OK. Defrost cycle usually starts by timer and end by thermorelay. Less wattage make just longer cycle.

Comment: @winny: https://pdxrvwholesale.com/products/dometic-referigerator-cooling-fins-heating-element-3850674015

Comment: If you are nervous with 7 elements, start with 6 and verify that your plan will work.  You might find that 6 is enough.

Comment: Whoa! You can design and have a flex-PCB like that one made custom for less money than that.

Comment: @winny - I picked up a "real" part for $130, but I plan to build this anyway as the part is used and probably 12+ years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heater you found has 7 W at 12 V. Five in parallel give 35 W. Two in series deliver 3.5 W, if we combine both, we get 38.5 W using 7 heaters.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0WkDU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you use 42 W instead of 40 W, you add 100*(42-40)/40=5%

Usually, resistors have a 5% tolerance (or even more for power resistors). So if your resistors are "average" and not on the bad end of the side, then you should be within the "tolerance range".

What's more, usually, electrical design is done with some margin. What's more, there is often some extra margin to account for external parameter ranges (mainly temperature), so as long as you stay well away from the temperature range limits, you should get some extra safety margin.

So I would say that the likelihood of destroying your supply is low (it might make it age a bit faster due to the slight overload).

If you want to be safe, just use only 5 elements (35 W): in the worst case, the defrosting is not perfect.
Or if you want to get even nearer, buy 7 elements, and put one pair in series (so that pair uses only 3.5 W), so you get a total of 38.5 W.

Personally, I would order 6 elements, but connect only 5 of them. If defrosting is not enough, then take the (small) risk of connecting the 6th.

Comment: Thanks for the response (and edit), I will follow your advice (connect 5 and keep a warm spare - pun intended) and hopefully not burn anything down.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get more precisely a power of 40 watts then, you need to match the six paralleled 7 watt elements to 3.6 Ω. Given that each 7 watt element is individually is 20.571 Ω then, in parallel, that's 3.4285 Ω i.e. a deficit of 0.1715 Ω for all six in parallel or, 1.029 Ω individually.

So, you could use 1 Ω resistors in series with each element to make the overall loading pretty much the same as the original element. The 1 Ω resistors would each dissipate about 0.34 watts and, if you were pedantic/OCB/shrewd about things, you could use the heat from those resistors also.